# SoundCloud returns 500 on all endpoints, but only on one machine

Tags: soundcloud

On my server, the soundcloud API returns a 500 server error:

```
$ curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?q=test&client_id=KEY'
<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>
An internal server error occured.
</body></html>
```

If I try to do this on my development machine, everything is fine and I get expected results. It seems as though SoundCloud banned the IP, `curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/'` returns a 500 as well. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If your program request frequently, soundcloud blocked your request, to prevent from block use proxy to post a request.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am not exceeding [the rate limits](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits). Are there any other limits?

Comment: then you should check your firewall setting and give permission to your program.

Comment: Having the same problem, appears not to be API key related as I've changed that and the problem still exists. Looks like it could be tied to IP address?

Comment: @RoryGilchrist SoundCloud's API has started working again without any action of mine. I assume that this was a temporary restriction from their side, but I didn't exceed any limits, so I am unsure why.

Comment: for regular request you must have use proxy in web request to prevent block IP Again.